# What is the Python docstring format supported by Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, docstring

How does VS Code interpret markup/markdown and layout in Python docstrings on mouse hover?

There are several issues reported for this display but there doesn't seem to exist any official info on what the current format is.

Comment: FYI, here is the [GitHub issue link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/38), which doesn't seem to progress much since the issue was opened 3 years ago. It is sort of put into back burner. If decent docstring rendering in IDE is needed, perhaps one would want to consider PyCharm instead.

Comment: . . . another 2 years later and this problem persists (with standard docstrings):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76172407/docstring-not-working-in-python-on-vs-code

Answer (score 35):

### VS Code renders markdown fine in mouse hovers - but doesn't render standard docstring formats well

The VS Code Python extension will use markdown that you put into a docstring for intellisense mouse hover information, but this doesn't really meet any of the commonly accepted/used docstring formats for Python. It doesn't properly layout any of those common formats (as of May 2020).

***Update (4/2023): Sphinx has been updated to support markdown in docstrings for its auto-code generation, meaning you can put all your docstrings in markdown and they will look good in VS Code hovers and also work with Sphinx***

So, your options are:

1. Stick with one of the major formats that will work with existing Python documentation tools and utilities like **Sphinx**
2. Use markdown in your docstrings and look good in VS Code, but be incompatible with most other documentation tools

---

### More Details / Example

The top 3 Python docstring formats are:

- Google
- Sphinx
- NumPY/ReST

VS Code will take ReST format (NumPY style) and properly layout the headers from each section (each item with the line of dashes under it), but in all the formats, the section content is unformatted and munged together with all the linebreaks dropped.

If you use markdown directly in the docstrings, it is supported, but then you aren't meeting the formatting requirements of docstrings for auto documentation frameworks like Sphinx. For example, I started with Sphinx format here and modified it to look better with VS Code's markdown tooltips

```py
def autodoc_test_numpy(self, a: str, b: int = 5, c: Tuple[int, int] = (1, 2)) -> Any:
    """[summary]

    ### Parameters
    1. a : str
        - [description]
    2. *b : int, (default 5)
        - [description]
    3. *c : Tuple[int, int], (default (1, 2))
        - [description]

    ### Returns
    - Any
        - [description]

    Raises
    ------
    - ValueError
        - [description]
    """
```

Will render like this:
[image]
[image]

Notice that the final "Raises" section here has the underlining with dashes that makes it a level 1 header (which is the ReST style). Look how big it is! I bumped the other down to `h3` by using `###` in front of the text instead of underlining it with hyphens on the next line.

Also, note that the [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) in the main function definition (like `str` in the `a: str`) render well (even colored) for args and the return type hint, but are not shown for kwargs (e.g. `b=5` without the type hint).

Comment: This was wrecking my brain, thanks for sharing! I couldn't get the correct formatting working, turns out all I had to do was switch to pycharm ;)

Comment: I'd say PyCharm has an edge on Code at the moment for Python. Too bad it doesn't handle 100 other languages as well... :)

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, there is no official format that is supported. The code has a few functions it runs to convert some parts of RST to Markdown to be displayed, but that is pretty much it.

The code that does the conversion can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/master/packages/pyright-internal/src/analyzer/docStringConversion.ts). The tests, which is a good way of seeing some actual examples, can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/master/packages/pyright-internal/src/tests/docStringConversion.test.ts).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, one way that I found was:

### Use `@param_name: The parameter's definition` for proper docs.

```py
class User:
    def __init__(self, username:str, password:str):
        """A class for a user
        @username: The name of the user.
        @password: A strong password for the user.
        """
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
```

and the VS code will show the `definitons` respective to the parameter. That is, when I am entering the `username` parameter, the `The name of the user` will be shown. Here is a pic: [image] and the other parameter: [image]

Comment: This also works for the `:param username: The name of the user.` style and the Google-style `Args:` list.

Answer (score -1):

The use of [sphinx.ext.napoleon](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html) is what you're looking for. When you activate it in conf.py, your normal Google or Google with types docstrings will be transformed into reStructured text then fed into Sphinx. The result is nice looking docs and nice looking (and easy to write!) docstrings. This extension is part of the Sphinx distribution as of April 2022.

Comment: Does that fix the way VS Code displays the tooltips for an object?

Comment: What do you mean “fix”? Napoleon allows Google style docstrings to be ingesteed into Sphinx and produces nice docs. If you like that format for the tooltips then yes.

Comment: The question is regarding the display of VS Code tooltips for Intellisense preview of a function docstring when you hover over a usage of it. This answer appears to only be concerned with Sphinx and separate documentation. VS Code does not render normal Python docstring formats very well.