# Vscode not displaying python doc string properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, docstring

Just moved from pycharm to vscode and noticed something strange when i hover over functions , the doc string is not being displayed properly.

[image]

Attaching a snapshot of the docstring using a jupyter notebook , the same applies if i just try the same in a normal .py file as well.

[image]

Just wondering if this is the normal way that doc strings are displayed in VS code or is there any extension that can make it more readable ?

Comment: I guess you missed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57017994/what-is-the-python-docstring-format-supported-by-visual-studio-code