# docstring not working in Python on VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, docstring

I use standard docstring format, there is a useful example here:
[What are the most common Python docstring formats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-are-the-most-common-python-docstring-formats)

So here is example code:

```py
def function(a: str, b:bool, c:int):
    ''' the function doc string. 
    Here is a bit more.
    
    args:
        a: a random string goes here (str)
        b: lets describe something binary (bool)
        c: we have a whole number (int)

    return:
        gives something back


    '''
    
    a = a + ' world'
    b = 5 * b
    c = 10 + c


    return c
```

When I hover over the function definition in VS Code, the description is nicely formatted. Each argument is on its own separate line:

[image]

But I like to add the types at the beginning, like this:

```py
def function(a: str, b:bool, c:int):
    ''' the function doc string. 
    Here is a bit more.
    
    args:
        a: (str) a random string goes here
        b: (bool) lets describe something binary
        c: (int) we have a whole number

    return:
        gives something back


    '''
    
    a = a + ' world'
    b = 5 * b
    c = 10 + c


    return c
```

Now when I hover over the function definition the args are all merged onto one line:

[image]

I notice that this is caused by the parentheses around the types and removing them removes the problem.

I also note that if I print the docstring, it looks how it should be, so it is like VS Code has an issue with the parentheses:

```py
print(function.__doc__)
```

returns this:

```
 the function doc string. 
    Here is a bit more.
    
    args:
        a: (str) a random string goes here
        b: (bool) lets describe something binary
        c: (int) we have a whole number

    return:
        gives something back
```

But why is this the case and how can I get it back to normal (keeping the parentheses)?

Comment: Shouldn't the type be _before_ the colon? That's what the linked examples show.

Comment: @jonrsharpe,  i tried that, but it had the same effect.  (i didnt include it because the question was long enough already)...  do you replicate the same issue ?  **specifically, the parenthesis before or immediately after the colon causes the issue**.

Comment: I get them on separate lines either way, but it makes much more sense to show something that matches what you've linked to (and still doesn't work) than something that doesn't. You've already got type annotations in the definition anyway.

Comment: Seems like the issue is how VSCode renders a string in its GUI and has nothing to do with python itself - it might be a minor visual bug in VSCode however. I'm struggling to choose a correct close reason for this question but I think it should not be here because minor visual bugs in third party software (as in, not your own code) don't feel like they should be on topic. I'd suggest opening an issue at the VSCode github repository or whereever they track bugs.

Comment: @l4mpi,  i hear what you say. however, i note that `vscode` is a major tag. If you do open an issue, it might be worth posting a link here.

Comment: @D.L I wouldn't even use that garbage editor if you offered to pay me for it, so no, I'm not going to open an issue. I'm just saying it's useless to ask this question on SO as this seems like a VSCode bug so it's unanswerable (the answer would be "it's a bug, wait for it to get fixed"). That we have a vscode tag doesn't change that fact.

Comment: @l4mpi,  you are correct (aside from a bias against a particular editor). I treat this as a bug and have reported the issue here:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/181499

Comment: Just an observation.   (btw, i fully support opening the formatting issue)  but isn't the extra text redundant?   The type does also show up in the function prototype in the hover.  Having it in the string too just gives you 2 places to maintain.   Kind of violates the DRY principle.

Comment: The issue was closed because it was python related, so it reopened here:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed. The error was pylance and upgrading to version `2023.5.21` allows for the types before the colon like so (which is the normal google doc format).

So this format now works:

```py
def function(a: str, b:bool, c:int):
    ''' the function doc string. 
    Here is a bit more.
    
    args:
        a (str): a random string goes here
        b (bool): lets describe something binary
        c (int): we have a whole number

    return:
        gives something back


    '''
    
    a = a + ' world'
    b = 5 * b
    c = 10 + c


    return c
```

The link to the github answer is here:

https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4377