# Vscode tooltip not rendering markdown format when hovering in functions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I used to comment my functions (in python at least) using a markdown format.
And it render it correctly showing the Heading level, the variables, and so on.
I do not know why it stopped working.

And it shows like this:

[image: screenshot showing raw Markdown in the Hover]

Comment: Did you disable/remove the [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) extension? 
Disabling that extension removes markdown comment rendering for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Markdown-style links in docstrings will now be passed through as-is to
> tooltips.

[Pylance 2021.4.3 (29 April 2021)](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#202143-29-april-2021) shows that it does not support Markdown format display.

There are many formats such as google/numpy/sphinx-style, which is difficult to achieve uniformity. Obviously, no format is the best format.

If you wish to use markdown, please disable Pylance. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61569286/18359438) may help you.